# How to use resample function in matlab on a set of data

Tags: matlab

I am a beginner in MATLAB. I have a question on how to use the [`resample`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/resample.html) function in matlab. I want to reduce the size of my data from 1881456 counts to half of it. My sample frequency is 128 Hz. However, the example shown in MATLAB documentation is quite confusing to me .

The function that I want to use is this :

```
y = resample(x,p,q)
```

The example given is like below:

```
fs1 = 10;
t1 = 0:1/fs1:1;
x = t1;
y = resample(x,3,2);
t2 = (0:(length(y)-1))*2/(3*fs1);
figure, clf
plot(t1,x,'*',t2,y,'o',-0.5:0.01:1.5,-0.5:0.01:1.5,':')
```

As stated above, the set of data is generated in the codes above by inserting the resampled data `y` into the `t2` equation whereas mine is already generated by the inertial sensor.

I need some advice and guide on how to use this simple "resample" function in MATLAB to resample my already generated sensor data.

Answer (score 2):

A simple example may be useful:

```
>> x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]; %// Example data. Size 1 x 10
>> y = resample(x, 1, 2) %// Reduce number of values to half (size 1 x 5)

y =

    1.0067    2.8928    5.2092    6.6297    9.7448
```

Comment: thank you so much ..i also think the way you did.. but i got errors.. =( the errors is like below :                                                                                                                 y=resample(AngularVelocityXhead,3,2);  
Error using dataset/subsrefParens (line 9)
Dataset array subscripts must be two-dimensional.

Error in dataset/subsref (line 69)
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = subsrefParens(a,s);

Error in upfirdn (line 71)
  x = x(:);  % columnize it.

Error in resample (line 119)
y = upfirdn(x,h,p,q);

Comment: You seem to be using a [`dataset`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/dataset.html) as your input data? (In my example I'm using a `vector`). If that's the case sorry, I don't know about datasets. Maybe you can convert your dataset into a vector, [using `double`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/dataset.double.html)